# Is it possible to update a SharePoint Online list item programatically? Not using the App Model

Tags: list, sharepoint-online

I recently signed up for a [SharePoint Online](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharepoint-online-online-collaboration-software-FX103789366.aspx) account.  I want to be able to run a local console application and populate a list hosted by my SharePoint online site.  **How can I do this**?

I've tried some code ([found here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/286f9205-2e06-4d95-b340-7097e550023d/cannot-contact-site-at-the-specified-url?forum=sharepointdevelopment) and [MSDN info found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179912.aspx)) that is supposed to pull list data, but it returns an error "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."  I know the goal is to *post* data, not *pull*, but I attempted it as a start.

[This site about the Client Object Model](http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/154/t/624.aspx) contains some additional info about using login information, but it also did not work.  There's some discussion in the comments about hijacking a session cookie from Internet Explorer, but this cannot be the best way to approach what should be a simple thing.  Lastly, there is a comment on this page that mentions the authentication service is turned off...so I am now wondering if is it possible?

I thought of using the List web service, but I don't know how to get the GUIDs from SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 0):

You need to leverage the claims authentication approach supported by SharePoint Online.  Best basic sample of this can be found here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Remote-Authentication-in-b7b6f43c/